# How to rank a list by looking at Comparison operators?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to compare the A list by looking at the comparison operators in the B list and I am trying to put the A list in your C list. List A and B can be from 1 to n. For example;

```
A = [1,2,33,8,3]
B = ["<",">","<","<"]
```

Output;

```
C=[1,33,2,3,8]
```

What algorithm can I install for this?

Comment: Have you done any analysis yourself? Given some thought about how you would solve such a problem?

Comment: honestly I couldn't create anything logical in my mind.At first I thought I should sort the list, but it didn't help.

Comment: One way to start is the brute-force method: try all possible permutations until one of them satisfies the conditions. Often, the act of implementing that solution, even though non-optimal, gives you ideas for creating a more efficient solution. Another way is to use pencil and paper, figure out how you would solve the solution by hand. If you can write down the steps you used, then you can implement those steps in code.

Comment: @Apple did you mean lists A and C can be from 1 to n? And list B can be from 1 to n-1? (I would assume the list of operators would need to be one less than the list of numbers?)

Comment: @Apple: use a general-purpose approach called "induction".  Assume you have such an algorithm when list a is of size "n". Now, what would you need to do to change the algorithm so it still works by adding just a single integer to list A?  (practically: find out how it works using just 3 numbers in list A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First sort `A`. identify the indexes of the first and last value in this sorted list.

Then iterate the comparators from list B. When it is `<`, take the value at the low end of A, and increment the corresponding index. When it is `>`, take the value from the other end, and decrement the corresponding index.

Here is an implementation in Python:

```py
def rankbycomparators(A, B):
    result = []
    A = sorted(A)
    lo = 0
    hi = len(A)-1
    for cmp in B:
        if cmp == "<":
            result.append(A[lo])
            lo += 1
        else:
            result.append(A[hi])
            hi -= 1
    result.append(A[lo])
    return result
```

Example use:

```
A = [1,3,4,6,8]
B = ["<",">","<","<"]
print(rankbycomparators(A, B))
```

Which outputs `[1, 8, 3, 4, 6]`